# Samsung GT-I9192 No Boot loop and can't enter recovery mode

Tags: recovery-mode, boot, odin, samsung-galaxy-s-4-mini

No Boot loop and can't enter recovery mode I tried to boot into recovery mode, the phone vibrates then does nothing. If I release the buttons it simply goes into charging mode. Also tried flash official rom with ODIN But nothing, write only: Setupinstalation this is last message in ODIN. what can i do?? thanks

---

i get Kies but in "Firmware emergency recobery" list is not anything try reinstall drivers but nothing.thanks for reply

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [Kies](http://www.samsung.com/ca/support/usefulsoftware/KIES/)? This is the way to go if you want to restore your firmware. After, you can go to recovery and factory reset.

Comment: i get Kies but in "Firmware emergency recobery" list is not anything try reinstall drivers but nothing.thanks for reply

Comment: I also have a very low rate of success with Kies, but I still hope it will help someone someday, haha